# How to strip down certain asset files for a given locale in Android app

Tags: android, apk, proguard

I have a feature (in our Android app) that is working in US, it has lot of files in asset folder.

US apk size : 20 MB & India apk size : 8 MB

If I end up porting all the files in the asset then even download size of India flavor would be 20 MB (which increases download size by more than 100%) and the approach is keep the size minimal & download the rest of asset dynamically (while in India flavor of the app).

Problem I have is: I do not know a method to strip down the asset files based on locale? Is there a way to 'ship all files in asset for US, while cutting it down for India' (For ex) ?

Please suggest any other alternatives.
I would like to release this feature in another country. Apparently size in assets folder increases the APK size of that country by 20MB (download size), this increase in APK size is not good (because users may not even try to install the app).

Is there a way to strip down the files in asset folder (based on locale)? OR is there any other method? Please suggest.

***** NOTE *****
Our app has not got 'Android app bundles' support yet from our release teams (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/introducing-google-play-asset-delivery.html)

Comment: You should clarify if everything is going into one APK file or you are using [Google Play Asset Delivery](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/introducing-google-play-asset-delivery.html)

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question, our app cannot use Google Play Asset Delivery (due to some restrictions). I'd appreciate if you know of any alternatives to this. Thanks!